# Malformed call to ChangeDisplaySettings() causing BSOD on Windows 7

Tags: windows, winapi, crash, bsod

The following program causes a BSOD on my fully patched Windows 7 machine and a Windows 7 machine of a colleague - the systems are very different configurations so I don't think it's a driver issue. It seems that something just can't handle a request for a display mode that only includes a zero display frequency. Here's the code that triggers a BSOD under Visual Studio 2012 Update 3:

```
#include <windows.h>

int APIENTRY WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    DEVMODE mode = { 0 };

    mode.dmSize = sizeof(DEVMODE);
    mode.dmFields = DM_DISPLAYFREQUENCY;

    ChangeDisplaySettings(&mode, CDS_FULLSCREEN);

    return 0;
}
```

Adding the following line prior to `ChangeDisplaySettings()` stops the BSOD occurring:

```
    mode.dmDisplayFrequency = 60;
```

The BSOD details are:

```
*** STOP 0x0000007E (0xFFFFFFFFC0000094, 0xFFFFF96000685577, 0xFFFFF88015313638, 0xFFFFF88015312E90)
***      cdd.dll - Address FFFFF96000685577 base at FFFFF96000680000, DateStamp 4d4a90a5
```

I'm posting this as a question because I'm interested if anyone else has noticed it or has any comments, and also so that a cause of this particular BSOD is out there in case it helps anyone in the future.

Also interested in whether others are able to reproduce it reliably as well.

If you post a thoughtful/interesting/relevant response/answer/discussion then the rep is yours!

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/security/advisory/2028859

Comment: You should update your display driver...

Comment: @JochenKalmbach It's already running fully patched genuine Windows 7 Home Premium with SP1, no driver updates available. Also the BSOD occurred on two separate machines, one is a laptop with an Intel HD 3000 GPU and the other is a desktop with a high-end NVIDIA GPU. So this stage I don't think buggy graphics drivers are to blame.

Comment: @Xearinox That CVE description says that it works via a "crafted image file", but my little code snippet doesn't do that. Also, the issue in that CVE was fixed by MS already so it shouldn't be able to cause mischief anymore anyway (on a fully up-to-date system).

Comment: @RichardNZ: do you need admin privilege to make the BSOD happen?  If not, you should submit that to secure@microsoft.com as a potential security vulnerability.  (I'm happy to submit it on your behalf if you prefer.)

Comment: @HarryJohnston: No you don't need admin privileges, in fact it BSODs here when run under the guest account. I'll have a look at submitting it to Microsoft ASAP, could be an interesting process to go through. I have no idea if the bug would be further exploitable, though a BSOD is bad enough!

Comment: @RichardNZ: by definition, if a user-mode process can cause a BSOD that's at least a denial-of-service attack.  Of course it might be in the vendor's device driver rather than being a MS bug.  If I can be of any help dealing with MS, my email address is in my profile.

Comment: @HarryJohnston The MS security guys understandably aren't interested in local DOS exploits, and suggested I report the issue to [Microsoft Product Support Services](http://support.microsoft.com/common/international.aspx). Although I suspect this is a bug in Windows and not in a display driver, due to time constraints I'm not going to take it any further. Trying to submit a small BSOD-causing C program via that support link smells like a bit of a wild goose chase to me, but feel free to look into it further if it takes your interest! PS: it's always nice to run into a fellow Kiwi online :-).